# share DispatchQueue and dispatch_queue_t between Swift3 and Objective-c code

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, swift3

As I am trying to migrate incrementally an App to Swift3 and have objective-C and Swift3 work together, I have solved most problems but the following:

In Objective-C, I used a global serial `dispatch_queue_t` in the app to dispatch all database operation as a way to avoid conflicts in writing to the database. Swift3 uses DispatchQueue now:

Is it possible to create a `DispatchQueue` that uses the same `dispatch_queue_t` queue so I can dispatch from Swift3 or Objective c to the same queue and continue to avoid conflict?

The main queue is clearly shared, so I hope it's possible, but couldn't find a way to achieve that for my own queue. So I had so far to pick one language (say Objective-C and dispatch_queue_t) and send all the swift request via an objective wrapper. I hope there is a better way to leverage both language native APIs

Thanks

Comment: A global (Objective-)C variable `dispatch_queue_t myDispatchQueue;` is exported to Swift as `public var myDispatchQueue: DispatchQueue!`, you can "just use it" from Swift. Can you specify what problems exactly you had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** You can just pass the `DispatchQueue` object to Objective C, it is the same object as the `dispatch_queue_t`.

---

`dispatch_queue_t` is defined like so in Objective C:

```
typedef NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue> *dispatch_queue_t;
```

Internally, a `OS_dispatch_queue` class [exists](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/lib/libdispatch.dylib/OS_dispatch_queue.h), which, according to [the Swift sources](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-3.0-branch/apinotes/Dispatch.apinotes), is mapped to `DispatchQueue`:

```
Classes:
- Name: OS_dispatch_object
  SwiftName: DispatchObject
- Name: OS_dispatch_queue
  SwiftName: DispatchQueue
```

It is then [further extended](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-3.0-branch/stdlib/public/SDK/Dispatch/Queue.swift) for Swift-specific API, but that API passes the `DispatchQueue` object directly into Objective C. See for instance call to `_swift_dispatch_sync`:

```
@available(OSX 10.10, iOS 8.0, *)
public func sync(execute workItem: DispatchWorkItem) {
    // _swift_dispatch_sync preserves the @convention(block) for
    // work item blocks.
    _swift_dispatch_sync(self, workItem._block)
}
```

`_swift_dispatch_sync` is [implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-3.0-branch/stdlib/public/stubs/DispatchShims.mm) like so:

```
void
swift::_swift_dispatch_sync(
    __swift_shims_dispatch_queue_t queue,
    __swift_shims_dispatch_block_t block)
{
    dispatch_sync(cast(queue), cast(block));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I had not tried the simple approach. Appreciate the detailed answer, very useful!

Comment: what is equal for `DispatchWorkItem` in Objective-C?

Comment: @user25 A block.

Comment: @LeoNatan I'm trying to do the same in Objective-C (cancel DispatchWorkItem which hasn't started yet) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749043/cancel-dispatchworkitem-in-objective-c-or-what-would-be-equal